# Extracting a specific column from a csv file

Tags: c#, csv

When I run this code it takes 11 elements in the first iteration. In the second iteration it's reduced to 6 elements and in the last it takes 1 element and then shows an "array out of range exception".

What am I doing wrong?

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(Path))
{  
    string [] column = line.Split(',');
    if (id == column[4])
    {
        return false;
    }
    Array.Clear(column, 0, column.Length);
}
```

Comment: What does your input look like? What is `id`? Assuming `id` is a string of some sort, IIRC, you can't compare `id` and `column[4]` in c#, there's a function to do that (`compare(id, column[4])` maybe?)

Comment: Do you mean CSV? If not, what is a CSF?

Comment: Did you check if your CSV file has 11 columns in all rows?

Comment: First off, what is wrong with what you've described?  The exception seems obvious but it's not apparent if there's something wrong with the 11-6-1 pattern.

Comment: i have to take 11 always i dont know why the array reduces to 6 then 1 ???

Comment: what is the idea behind the "Array.Clear" call ? column is being assigned again on each iteration of the foreach.

Comment: i just tried to empty the array, but its giving same error without Array.clear

Comment: what is the value of id? What is this method doing? Are you just trying to grab the 4th value in the 11 values it reads in? What is the purpose of returning false? I can help but I really don't know what you're trying to achieve here.

Comment: i have to match id which is int value to fourth coliumn in myu csv file and i think @sthotakura is right... his answer is: Did you check if your CSV file has 11 columns in all rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried making sure that the row being check has enough columns ?

By 4th column you mean the column at index 4 ? or you mean the 4th column which is at index 3 ?

```
private bool SomeMethod(String path, String id)
{
    string [] column ;

    foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(Path))
    {  
        column = line.Split(',');

        //check that there are at least 5 columns before comparing it with ID
        if ((column.Length >= 5) && (id == column[4]))
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: index is fourth and column is fifth

Answer (score 0):

If you say line has only 1 element on the 3rd iteration, then you make column = line.Split(','), column will have 1 element.  so at that point column[4] is "out of range" as the string array only has one element in it.

What exactly are you trying to do with this though, so we can give you an answer better than just the exception.

edit: So by your comment all you have to do is see if the 5th column matches what's in id and return false if so?

```
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(Path))
{  
    string [] column = line.Split(',');
    if (column.Count() >= 5 && column.id == column[4])
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

this will ensure you have at least 5 elements in your column array before you try to access the 5th element column[4] in the == check.

Comment: i have to match id with 4th column

Comment: From what you said, on the 3rd time through column only contains 1 element. column[4] means the 5th element in the string array column. but going back to what you said, there is only 1 element, meaning column[0] is the only element in the array.  This is exactly what is causing your exception.   We need to know what id contains or is supposed to contain, possibly what your input looks like, and maybe more of the method that this foreach is contained in. What is the method that this resides in supposed to be doing?

Comment: i just debugged and checked, id is a number and column[4] contains id in my csv file so i have to match id by every row in my csv file to forth column. did you got my point ?